# How to insert empty array into jsonb column (pgsql) by Yii2?

Tags: postgresql, yii2, jsonb

1. Created a migration with a new field of jsonb type, not null and default value = **[]**. (example of stored data: **["235", "214"]**) and add a rule to model **[['unique_users'], 'safe']**

```
    public function up()
    {
        $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE offer ADD unique_users jsonb not null default \'[]\'';
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql, []);
        $command->queryAll();
    }
```

**Result**: Added a **unique_users** field with a default value **[]** to each row. **jsonb_typeof(unique_users)** returns an **array** type.

[image]

2. Created needed query for test

```
select jsonb_array_length(unique_users) from test where unique_users @> '"19"'::jsonb
```

**Result from PgAdmin**:

[image]

It seemed that everything was ready. But after saving a new record with **Yii2**, I received a query error:

> ERROR: you can not get the length of a scalar

And I saw that another value was recorded in the field - **""**

[image]

I was tryed to add the validation rule to Model: **['unique_users', 'default', 'value' => '[]'],**.
**Result:**

[image]

...with the same problem of query - value is not an array. **jsonb_typeof(unique_users)** returns an **string** type.

**How to insert empty array into jsonb column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['unique_users', 'default', 'value' => []],
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're accidentally sending an empty string as the value for your `unique_users` field. If the value would be completely empty it should take the default DB value for the column. Please make sure the `unique_users` field is completely empty (`null`) when saving.

You can however also do this with a default value rule. This should do the trick:

```
['unique_users', 'default', 'value' => json_encode([])],
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was tryed it too - the same result **"[]"**. **jsonb_typeof(unique_users)** of new row returned string type. Any ideas?

Comment: Very weird. Works perfectly for me. Are you 100% sure the value (`$yourModel->unique_users`) is NULL when calling `->save()` ?

Comment: It depends on validation rule:
if default value is **json_encode([])** - the unique_users = **""**

Comment: ... I just tried to set default value = [] again and it worked! Thanks to everyone! It seems that someone has worked a lot today)